# MySQL: How to tell if a cell value has changed?

Tags: mysqli

I am pulling data from table `Supervisors`.  Through each iteration, I want to know when `Supervisor`.`SupNum` changes.  If the value changes, do this.  If it stays the same, do the other.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

> if (Supervisor.SupNum = chk) then 
>   flag =true; else 
>   chk := Supervisor.SupNum; flag =false end if;

If you want the first iteration to be true then have another iterator i.

> if (i=0) then Supervisor.SupNum := chk; end if; i++;

Comment: I want to see if the value of the field `Supervisors`.`SupNum` changes or remains the same through the next iteration.  So, if `SupNum` = 3 on one round, and the next time it is = 43, throw up a flag

Comment: This isn't an answer, it should be posted as a comment. Since you don't have enough rep to post comments, you should just wait for someone else to ask the question.